# How do I sort paragraph types?

Tags: views, paragraphs

Hello it is possible to order the output of the paragraphs for example

Type of content Blog
I create a blog details field that calls the type of paragraphs and there I select image and description

In my content it goes in this order

- 1 Image
- 2 Description

In the view I call that field
blog details
and they appear to me
but based on the order of the node

But I don't want it to look like this

- 1 description
- 2 image

and always look in that order

Comment: Why not make separate fields for image and description of they're always in a specific order?

Comment: Hello, within a paragraph field I can choose between several types of paragraphs, in this case I have an image paragraph and a description paragraph and a single widget button that allows me to add which one I want like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ofvV.png

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Sorry. Are we you trying to show only the description and image paragraphs in your view? In your image I see 5 total paragraphs, are you trying to show a subset of the total paragraphs added to your field, and show them in a specific order?

Comment: Hello exactly in the view it is shown according to the order that was saved in the node

But I want a different order of sight

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to sort the values of a field at the view level. However, you can easily get the results you want by creating a custom field formatter and then using it to render your field in the view.

You can read more about field formatters by reading the [Create a custom field formatter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-1) documentation on d.o.

Create a custom formatter that extends the formatter you're using now. I'm guessing you're using the default ERR formatter so you'll want to extend *Drupal\entity_reference_revisions\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\EntityReferenceRevisionsEntityFormatter*.

You'll need to override *viewElements()* or *getEntitiesToView()* - I'd override *getEntitiesToView()*.

```
protected function getEntitiesToView(EntityReferenceFieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
  // Let the parent class get all entities in the field first.
  $all_entities = parent::getEntitiesToView($items, $langcode);
  $my_entities = [];

  // Get first Description paragraph.
  $desc = $this->getFirstOfType($all_entities, 'MY_DESCRIPTION_BUNDLE');
  if (!empty($desc)) {
    $my_entities[] = $desc;
  }

  // Get first Image paragraph.
  $img = $this->getFirstOfType($all_entities, 'MY_IMAGE_BUNDLE');
  if (!empty($img)) {
    $my_entities[] = $img;
  }

  return $my_entities;
}

protected function getFirstOfBundle($entities, $bundle) {
  foreach($entities as $entity) {
    if ($entity->bundle() == $bundle) {
      return $entity;
    }
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering I wish I could do it from the views but I will try to use your example